# I have tkinter.TclError:

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is my python code

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from random import randint

root= Tk()
root.title("Quiz Countries")
root.iconbitmap("C:/Users/allen/Documents/Code")
root.geometry("600x600")



def countries_answer():
  answer: answer_input.get()
  answer: answer.replace(" ","")

  if answer.lower() == our_country[rando]:
    response = "Correct!" + our_country[rando]
  else:
    response = "Incorrect!" + our_country[rando].title()

  answer_label.config(text=response)



def country():
  hide_all_frames()
  countries_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)


  global our_country
  our_country = ["Vietnam", "Australia", "America", "Japan", "China", "Korea"]

  global rando
  rando = randint(0, len(our_country) -1) 
  countries = "Image/" + our_country[rando] + ".jpg"

  global countries_image
  countries_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(countries))
  show_countries = Label(countries_frame, image=countries_image)
  show_countries.pack(pady=15)

  
  global answer_input
  answer_input = Entry(countries_frame, font=("Helvetica", 18))
  answer_input.pack(pady=15)

  rando_button = Button(countries_frame, label="Pass", conmmand=country)
  rando_button.pack(pady=10)

  answer_button = Button(countries_frame, label="Answer", conmmand=countries_answer)
  answer_button.pack(pady=5)
  
  global answer_label
  answer_label = Label(countries_frame, label="", font=("Helvetica", 18))
  answer_label.pack(pady=15)


def hide_all_frames():
  for widget in countries_frame.winfo_children():
    widget.destroy()

  


  countries_frame.pack_forget()
 

my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)


country_menu = Menu(my_menu)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Geography", menu=country_menu)
country_menu.add_command(label="country", command=country)

country_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)



countries_frame = Frame(root, width=600, height=600)

root.mainloop()
```

The code runs and it is showing the program but I can't find the button to answer my work.
After I run the code it shows like under and it has an error but I don't know what.
I have already searched for it but still don't know.

[image: this is the error]
so, what is wrong with my code?

Please help me fix this code

Comment: Please don't post a picture of an error. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format the error directly in the question. Pictures of errors aren't searchable, copyable, and cannot be seen at all by the visually impaired.

Comment: You can answer your own question by reading the documentation for the Button widget, where you can see a list of valid options.

Comment: error shows `unknown option "-label"` and few lines earlier `Button(...., label....)` and  and this should be clue to your problem.

Comment: And what's `answer: answer_input.get()`. Is that correct in python

Answer (score 1):

Buttons do not have labels. You can use text instead -

```
answer_button = Button(countries_frame, text="Answer", conmmand=countries_answer)
```

Comment: already try it but still cannot
the unknown option will change from "-label" to "-command"

Comment: @HaiNguyen What do you mean? If you do as said in the answer, `command` is a valid option.

Comment: I know. Change the word label to text, don't change command for this problem

Comment: Typo error: `conmmand` should be `command` instead.